# Best Buy Reviews API does not return results newer than 2 days old

Tags: best-buy-api

The Best Buy Reviews API seems to return results that are at least 2+ days old.  Is it possible to force the API to return fresher results?

Here's the call I used: [http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/reviews(sku%20in(*[SKUs]*))?apiKey=*[API*](http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/reviews(sku%20in(_[SKUs]_))?apiKey=_[API) key]&sort=submissionTime.asc&pageSize=100&show=sku,rating,submissionTime&page=1

When I call this for some popular SKUs that get many reviews each day on bestbuy.com, the most recent reviews returned from the API will be from two days ago.

Answer (score 0):

While we are working to get the review data to be less stale via the API, you are unfortunately correct in your observation about the lag between Bestbuy.com and the Review API.

This is due to the various delays in processing and sanitization of the review data before it ends up in Reviews API.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks Steve.  Looking forward to that improvement.  One other feature request (or maybe it already exists): can the API report back whether a review is from a "verified purchaser?"